# Automation that will automatically update app icon after its updated

Tags: macos, applescript, applications, automation, icon

I have a lot of apps where the icons are just unpleasant and I've made much better ones that I have applied. while some apps rarely update a good amount of them do which of course mean the original app icon is restored since its a new package.

My goal is to some how create an automation (ideal) or very least a script, that will identify all my apps that have replaced icons, and when the app is updated, then automaticly replace the icon with the one chosen. I tend to just use get info and drop the icon over the old one in the top left corner.

I would be nice if there was an app to manage all this, if I was good at code id totally make one lol. but just asking to see if anyone has any ideas.

Note: I am disabled and my end goal is to make my life a bit easier since it hard to remember to do all this stuff. thanks.

Comment: Using GUI scripting is a bit fragile and ugly.  AppleScriptObjC can be used to set a custom icon, how are you referencing the applications and their icon images?

Comment:  well all Im doing currently is the manual method of using the apps “get info” and dragging my new icon on top of the current one. 

I wouldn’t know where to start with making a script or code. 

I did however find to apps (Pictogram and Replaceicon for macOS) just for this purpose but they don’t work (figures)